# Boostrap padding (p-)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I use padding on a column `p-4` it looks uneven, the bottom seems to have more padding then the top.

Example:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-success p-4">
   <h6>Title</h6>
</div>
```

If I use this, it fixes the problem `(pt-4 pb-3)`

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-success pt-4 pb-3">
   <h6>Title</h6>
</div>
```

But `p-4` should apply padding to top, right, bottom left equally. Am I doing something wrong that causes this problem?

Full code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-success pt-4 pb-3">
                <h6>Title</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-danger p-4">
                <h6>Title</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-success p-4">
                <h6>Title</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-danger p-4">
                <h6>Title</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-success p-4">
                <h6>Title</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-danger p-4">
                <h6>Title</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `h6` has `margin-bottom: .5rem`. Set `m-0` for `h6` and see the result.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-success p-4">
      <h6 class="m-0">Title</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-danger p-4">
      <h6 class="m-0">Title</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-success p-4">
      <h6 class="m-0">Title</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-danger p-4">
      <h6 class="m-0">Title</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-success p-4">
      <h6 class="m-0">Title</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-danger p-4">
      <h6 class="m-0">Title</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```